# How to make these string matching functions in Clojure(Script)?

Tags: string, clojure, clojurescript

Consider the following multi-line string `S`:

```
apple
banana berry
cantelope
```

I'm trying to write/locate clojure functions which I will call in this post `or-match` and `and-match`. Here are some examples of what they should do:

```
(or-match S "apple" "berry")

;; should return the two line string:
;; apple
;; banana berry

(and-match S "apple" "berry") ; should return nil

(and-match S "banana berry") ; should return a single line containing "banana berry"
```

How to make such functions in clojure(script)?

Comment: There's not anything wrong with this, but I'm curious why you're asking the same question on both the haskell and clojure tags. Trying to decide which language to use for a task, or something?

Comment: Yes -- I'm comparing how these two languages approach this problem. I already built something in clojure using a different approach, and am switching to Haskell (a new language for me) and am wanting to use this better technique (comparing how the solution looks in each language along the way!)

Answer (score 2):

you can check that every/any candidate is present in a string:

```
user> (defn or-match [s & items]
        (filter (fn [line]
                  (some #(clojure.string/includes? line %)
                        items))
                (clojure.string/split-lines s)))
#'user/or-match

user> (or-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                "apple" "berry")
("apple" "banana berry")

user> (defn and-match [s & items]
        (filter (fn [line]
                  (every? #(clojure.string/includes? line %)
                          items))
                (clojure.string/split-lines s)))
#'user/and-match

user> (and-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                 "apple" "berry")
()

user> (and-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                 "banana berry")
("banana berry")
```

and since these functions just differ by one function (`some` vs `every?`), you can generalize it:

```
user> (defn get-lines-matcher [check]
        (fn [s & items]
          (filter (fn [line]
                    (check #(clojure.string/includes? line %) items))
                  (clojure.string/split-lines s))))
#'user/get-lines-matcher

user> (def and-match (get-lines-matcher every?))
#'user/and-match

user> (def or-match (get-lines-matcher some))
#'user/or-match

user> (or-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                "apple" "berry")
("apple" "banana berry")

user> (or-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                "apple" "berry")
("apple" "banana berry")

user> (and-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                 "apple" "berry")
()

user> (and-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                 "banana berry")
("banana berry")

user> (and-match "apple\nbanana berry\ncantelope"
                 "banana" "berry")
("banana berry")
```